# How to set rails_env for a script or batch file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I put my batch file in lib folder
and use rails db configuration, active-record like this.

```
require "#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/../config/environment.rb"

class Batch
  def hello
    Message.new do |t|
      t.title = "hello"
      t.save
    end
  end
end

batch = Batch.new
batch.hello
```

when excute batch

```
ruby lib/batch.rb
```

in development environment it's ok

but production environment still save development database...

how do i set rails_env batch.rb like this

```
ruby lib/batch.rb RAILS_ENV=production
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To initialise the Rails environment, instead of putting

```
require "#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/../config/environment.rb"
```

launch your batch file using `script/runner` and specify the environment with the `-e` option

e.g.

```
script/runner -e production lib/batch.rb
```

I think the above is The Rails Way of writing and executing a script that needs the Rails framework initialised in order to work. The alternative, as [neutrino](https://stackoverflow.com/users/125805/neutrino) says, is to prefix the command with RAILS_ENV=*value* e.g.

```
$ RAILS_ENV=production lib/batch.rb
```

This is a standard shell feature to set an environment variable prior to executing a command.

Answer (score 2):

Just FYI without script/runner :

```
RAILS_ENV=production ruby lib/batch.rb
```